# Origen de "adrián"

Tags: historia, sustantivos, palabras-raras, cuerpo-humano

"Adrián" figura desde antiguo (en forma plural desde el diccionario de Percival de 1591) como:

> El **callo que se cría en los pies**

En 1884 cambió a la definición [actual](https://dle.rae.es/adri%C3%A1n):

> 1. m. **juanete** (‖ hueso del dedo grueso del pie).

¿Cómo se produjo ese cambio, de "callo que se cria en los pies" a "hueso" y más concretamente del dedo grueso del pie??

Comment: Difícil. Es curioso que, en el NTLLE, todas las versiones de "adrian" con el significado de "callo" no tienen acento en la *a*, mientras que las que significan "juanete" sí tienen acento.

Comment: @wimi: Tienes razón, pero ¿puede ser por cambios en las normas de acentuación hacia 1880?

Comment: mmm sí, puede ser, porque parece que con "canción" pasa lo mismo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede que hacia el siglo XVI el significado de *adrián* no estuviera totalmente asentado, y significara diferentes cosas (según la región o incluso que fuera una palabra polisémica). Cierto es que los diccionarios del siglo XVIII recogen únicamente el significado de "callo", pero me gustaría llamar la atención sobre dos textos de Fray Antonio de Guevara:

> Es previlegio de viejos que todas las veces que se quexan, o coxean de alguna hinchaçón en el tobillo, o de algunos adrianes endurescidos, o de algunas uñas sobre salidas, o de algunas venas enconadas, si por caso les preguntan sus vecinos si es su mal gota, juran y perjuran que no es sino una rascadura.

> Yo vergüença he de oír decir "bésoos las manos", y muy grande asco he de oír decir "bésoos los pies", porque con las manos limpiámonos las narices, con las manos nos limpiamos la lagaña, con la mano nos rascamos la sarna y aun nos servimos con ellas de otra cosa que no es para decir en la plaça. Cuanto a los pies, no podemos negar sino que por la mayor parte andan sudados, traen largas las uñas, están llenos de callos y andan acompañados de adrianes y aun cubiertos de polvo o cargados de lodo.

Según el fichero general de la RAE, el primer texto es de 1524 y el segundo es de 1533. Dado que el primer texto habla de "adrianes endurecidos", es de suponer que su significado sea el de "callo", que son los que se pueden endurecer (los juanetes son ya duros por definición). Sin embargo, el segundo texto habla de que los pies "están llenos de callos y andan acompañados de adrianes". Aunque es posible que el autor quisiera repetir el significado, me resulta raro que dijera que una cosa anda acompañada de otra que es la misma. Por tanto, en este texto (separado nueve años del anterior) es posible que los adrianes se refieran a los juanetes, una de las afecciones más comunes que podían sufrir los pies de la época y que no se mencionan de forma expresa, salvo que lo haga a través del sustantivo "adrianes".

Más allá de esto, el problema que veo es que esos dos textos son los únicos que encuentro que usan la palabra. En el CORDE no me aparecen más, en el CREA menos aún, y en la hemeroteca y en Google Books solo encuentro textos que citan estos dos ya presentados. Luego me temo que sencillamente el cambio de significado en el diccionario sea una tentativa por intentar dilucidar qué quiso decir realmente con "adrianes" Fray Luis de Guevara. Fíjate además que el diccionario del doctor Francisco del Rosal de 1611 dice que "adrianes" eran "los juanetes de los pies". Y estamos hablando de una persona que practicaba la medicina en Córdoba. Quizá sus etimologías no fueran las más precisas, pero supongo que sabía de qué hablaba en lo que a afecciones del pie se refiere.

Mi teoría es, por tanto, que el vulgo inicialmente usaba "adrianes" de forma indistinta tanto para los callos como para los juanetes en la expresión oral, aunque técnicamente debía usarse solo para los juanetes. Esto explicaría el cambio de significado en los textos de Fray Luis de Guevara, al darse cuenta de esto o sencillamente asentarse el uso de la palabra. Rosal recoge el significado como "juanete" a principios del siglo XVII y la RAE optó por creer que en ambos textos (que aparecen los dos en el *Autoridades* del siglo XVIII) el significado es el de "callo", modificando (o corrigiendo) este significado en el siglo XIX.